# Connecting Github to jenkins failing

Tags: git, github, jenkins, devops, clone

I am new for Jenkins and when I try to connect and clone my GitHub repository with Jenkins server I am getting below error. I tried to solve this for 2 days but no luck. Can someone help me on this?

```bash
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/opt/java/openjdk/bin/Git-2.43.0-64-bit.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/Emanuel-Afro/Marvin-IT-Services.git HEAD" returned status code 1:
stdout:
stderr: <3>WSL (197) ERROR: UtilGetPpid:1293: Failed to parse: /proc/1/stat, content: 1 (tini) S 0 1 1 0 -1 1077936384 504 0 0 0 4 49 0 0 20 0 1 0 83261540 2531328 222 18446744073709551615 94412274446336 94412274453789 140736124239408 0 0 0 0 3145728 0 1 0 0 17 2 0 0 0 0 0 94412274465552 94412274467979 94412278300672 140736124247472 140736124247515 140736124247515 140736124248042 0
```

I expect my GitHub to be connected with my Jenkins server and clone the mentioned repository to my Jenkins server from GitHub.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please have a look at [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your context is way too vague to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. On the git credentials, if you are using username and password, use your personal access token as a password. Then set the path on the global configuration to the default, "git".